# Transfer TouchEvent from one view to another view

Tags: android

I am working with a Android Keyboard and a Popupwindow which opens after long pressing the keyboard key. I would like to transfer the MotionEvent DOWN from the keyboard to PopupWindow directly, so that user doesnot have to do Action UP and again DOWN to click on the popupkeyboard.

This is what I've done in OnLongPress:

```
@Override
protected boolean onLongPress(AppKeyboard.Key popupKey) {
        showPopup(popupKey);
        return true;
}

public void showPopup(AppKeyboard.Key popupKey) {
    ContextThemeWrapper ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    FontsKeyboardView keyboardView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popup_keyboard_view);
    keyboardView.setClipToOutline(true);
    AppKeyboard keyboard = new AppKeyboard(context, R.xml.popup_test);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(ctx);
    popupWindow.setContentView(popupView);
    popupWindow.setAttachedInDecor(false);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    getLocationInWindow(this.windowOffset);
    int i = this.windowOffset[0] + popupKey.x;
    popupView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    measuredHeight=popupView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int heightoffset= (this.windowOffset[1] + popupKey.y) - measuredHeight;
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(measuredHeight), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(this, 0, i, heightoffset);

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    if (this.popupWindow != null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            motionEvent = translateToPopupCoordinates(motionEvent, 1);
            motionEvent.recycle();

            PopupWindow popupWindow2 = this.popupWindow;

            this.popupWindow = (PopupWindow) null;

            popupWindow2.dismiss();

            return true;

        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            View contentView = popupWindow.getContentView();

            if (!contentView.isAttachedToWindow()) {
                return true;
            }
            motionEvent = translateToPopupCoordinates(motionEvent, 0);

            popupWindow.getContentView().onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            motionEvent.recycle();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final MotionEvent translateToPopupCoordinates(MotionEvent motionEvent, int i) {
    long downTime = motionEvent.getDownTime();
    long eventTime = motionEvent.getEventTime();
    float x = ((float) this.windowOffset[0]) + (motionEvent.getX() - ((float) this.windowPopupOffset[0]));
    float y = (motionEvent.getY() - ((float) this.windowPopupOffset[1])) + ((float) this.windowOffset[1]);
    PopupWindow popupWindow = this.popupWindow;
    View contentView = popupWindow.getContentView();
    motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, i, x, Math.min(y, ((float) contentView.getHeight()) - ((float) 1)), motionEvent.getMetaState());
    return motionEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onLongPress` returns a `boolean` which represents whether the event was handled by that method or it should be propagated further. If you return `true`, you're basically saying "I have handled this event, no need to propagate". So you can actually pass `false` there and then the event will be passed to the next `View` in the queue for handling that event. You might have to tweak it slightly to get it to work for your use-case.

Comment: I tried returning false but unfortunately it's not working. I have updated the code with motion event code.

Comment: I assumed it wouldn't work, because the view that appears does not belong in the hierarchy for the onClick event because it wasn't there. So I think you're trying to do something that's not really doable

Comment: no, it's working but only problem I'm facing right now is pressed key is not returning to normal state, it's still pressed after ACTION_UP is triggered

Comment: here is the video showing what's not working https://youtu.be/QRiLLqrejZ0